# All traceback displayed when request timeout fails in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just added a timeout for the requests I do in my tests. However, I'm getting a very long traceback about everything requests is doing, which is greatly impacting how quick I get feedback from the tests.

Assume this example:

```
import requests
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def meeeh():
    try:
        return requests.get('https://google.com', timeout=0.000000000000000000000000000001)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        print(e)
        raise SystemExit(1)


def test_meh(meeeh):
    print(meeeh.text)
```

The requests obviously fail because of that timeout. However, upon raising `SystemExit` a veeeeeeeeery long traceback (in fact, can't get to the beginning) which ends with the actual error message:

`-------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout setup --------------------------------------------------------
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10bb0e358>, 'Connection to google.com timed out. (connect timeout=1e-30)'))`

Now, if instead of one test I have 20 tests depending on that fixture, all of them fail, I'll be able to read just the output of the latest test because of this long traceback.

So... how can I remove the traceback at all?

Many questions I've read said that it's because I'm not capturing the exception, but I am. Others said to set `sys.trackbacklimit=None` but it isn't working either.

Comment: Look into calling `pytest` with the [`--tb` argument](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#modifying-python-traceback-printing) the default is `auto` which is fairly verbose, but maybe you'd prefer `line` for example

Comment: @CoryKramer that's far better!

Comment: `raise SystemExit(1) from None`?